# Good practices to split class in maven modules

Tags: java, class, maven, architecture

I'm currently trying to split a java project into several modules. For maintenance and reusability purpose, and I guess it's a good idea because i see the different dependencies between class.

However, i have two questions regarding to the splitting process.

- **Circular class references**: sometimes i have circular references between my classes. I assume it's strongly coupling and they should be put in the same module. Is that a good choice  ?
- **Vertical vs horizontal splitting**: I'm not really familiar, but i read some article about that though. I don't know how i should make the separation. If i have several classes that performs a feature, does they need to be group together into one module (for example: "database management")

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using microservices?

Comment: circular class reference is an identification that your design is not ok...Decoupling...

Comment: @jpganz18: I don't know really what is microservices, although i read some stuff about it. So i have not considered it.

Comment: I recommend you, in the case you have redundant use of modules and they are somehow connected each other, to read about microservices, it could help you a lot.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I agree, that i should decouple these parts of code. But is it always a "bad" things to have circular references ?

Comment: Circular references show that you have a design problem...

Comment: An interesting answer about why circular references are bad: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular class references: 
Maven will not let you have two modules that depend on each other. That won't compile. Until you can decouple those classes, they will have to be in the same module.

As for splitting your project to modules,
the separation should be about (surprise) modularity of your product. Modules will allow you to deploy specific parts of the project as appropriate for the environment, rather than deploying everything. For example you might have separate modules for server side code, client side code and common code. Clients will not need the server side logic, so it should not be part of the deployment for them.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting an answer like that. Do you have some pointer/best practices to avoid circular class references ? I'm trying to use as many as interface as possible but still got some of them!

Comment: The book Code Complete, chapter 6, explaining Abstract Data Types, encapsulation and information hiding, is extremely helpful to design clean, good interfaces and classes.